# WPF, bind specific item of a List to a TextBlock

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a List of doubles. I want to bind a specific item of this list to a TextBlock. This specific item is determined by another control (ComboBox):

```
<ComboBox Name="MyBox">
....
</ComboBox>

<TextBlock Binding="{MyList, >get item index == MyBox.SelectedIndex< }"/>
```

The solution I have in place right now, is to bind the TextBlock to another property of my context, however, I would prefer the other way as this forces me to have several Property Changed Notifications in place...

Thanks.

Comment: `<TextBlock Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>` - if the doubles list is used as ItemsSource of the Combobox.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for pointing that out! I will have a look.

Comment: Why did you accept the answer when it doesn't work, i.e. when the Combobox contains other element than those from the list you want to show in the TextBlock?

Comment: @Clemens I don't think there is a perfect solution for this, at least not the way I would expect it to work <TexBlock Text="{Binding MyList[Box.SelectedIndex]}"/>

Comment: That would easily be done with a MultiBinding and an appropriate converter. Or an additional view model property. If an answer does not solve the problem in the question, you should not accept it. The answer does simply not work if the TextBlock is supposed to display a text that is not a property of an item in the ComboBox.

Comment: @Clemens I guess you are right.

Comment: I guessed the easiest way would be to bind the ComboBox's SelectedIndex to a view model property, which in turn sets another view model property to which the TextBlock is bound.

Comment: Yup, I just expected WPF to have a way of indexing an element without so much trouble.

Comment: It has, but only with a constant expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that fits my needs, it involves using MultiBinding and a Converter:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GenericMemConverter}">
            <Binding Path="TotalGPUMemory"/>
            <Binding ElementName="CurPlatformView" Path="SelectedIndex"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

As you can see, I'm pointing to another control of the app and passing *SelectedIndex*.

Converter:

```
    public object Convert(object[] o, Type type, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        List<long> vals = (List<long>)o[0];
        int plat = (int)o[1];

        double mb = (double)vals[plat] / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
        return mb.ToString("N1") + "MB";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reference another control in the `.xaml` using `ElementName=_` within the binding, then specify the path of the binding using `Path=_`, like so:

```
<ComboBox Name="MyBox">
....
</ComboBox>

<TextBlock Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

Comment: Uhmm, that is not going to work straight away as the Items in the ComboBox are not the same as the text I want to display. However, I guess I could hold an object in this ComboBox and use "Path" to point to a property... Still this looks a bit ugly!

Comment: @Nacho yes, you can add SelectedItem.TextProperty ... btw not that ugly that's binding in WPF, it can get worse ;)

Comment: @Alfie yeah.. binding gotta love it! So I say it won't work as the combo box holds something like this "{PC,0} {LINUX,1} {XBOX,2}". But, this TexBlock shows some text that has nothing to do with the above (we just need the 0,1,2 index to get another element).

Comment: @Alfie Exactly that.

Comment: @Nacho this is because the `TextBlock` is using the `ToString()` method of the object, either override the `ToString()` method of the object to return the correct value or specify the value in the binding like so: `<TextBlock Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyBox, Path=SelectedItem.MyDisplayString}"/>`

Comment: @Alfie Yeah I'm aware of that, I was just hoping there was an alternative solution to just specify the index I want within a binding.